# Javascript: how to separate bytes in a string

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a bytes like this:

```
"b'ab' b'xy'"
```

Now I want to split it into two separate bytes and then will convert it into string. The out should look like:

```
"b'ab'"   
"b'xy'"
```

I tried javascript slicing but it won't work as this is a stream of data. So previously if I have these `"b'ab' b'xy'"` bytes then in the next turn it could be `"b'abc' b'xyz'"`

Comment: Bytes? Don't you just want to split on whitespace? Or do you want to specifically match the pattern `b'…'`?

Comment: yeah I could just split by whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `byte.split(/\s/)` as you have each byte separated by a whitespace. So, you could also do `byte.split(' ')` but if you have multiple whitespaces between the bytes then it would be better to use `\s` to be on safe side:

```js
var byte = "b'ab' b'xy'";
var res = byte.split(/\s/);
res.forEach((byte) => {
   document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div> Byte: '+byte+'</div>';
   console.log(byte)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. But lets say instead of console.log I want to write the output to two different divs. For example previously I was doing `$("#word").text(e.data);` But now as we have split the word can I write the output to different divs

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha cool, check the updated answer. And let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes. Thanks man. But the thing is could we just remove the foreach loop part. Because as I said I have stream of data. So this foreach is creating many divs which almost covers the whole screen

Comment: I mean couldn't it be just like `$(#word1).text(byte1)` and `$(#word2).text(byte2)`

Comment: Thanks for the help.